# Special character in path to open SQLite database connection

Tags: java, database, sqlite, classnotfoundexception, sqlitejdbc

I am trying to get a connection to a SQLite database (using Eclipse on Windows 8). Everything workes fine as long as the path name doesn't contain any special characters (like "é"). I tried to convert it to UTF-8 (because I read on http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html that it should be), but it didn't work. I get an "out of memory" exception (SQLException) what means that no database file was found.

This is the code summary of what I did:

```
public static String DB_PATH = "jdbc:sqlite:" + System.getProperty("user.home") + "<Rest of the path><databasename>.sqlite";

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
{
  // load the sqlite-JDBC driver using the current class loader
  Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

 Connection connection = null;
 try
 {
   // create a database connection
   connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_PATH);
   Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
   statement.setQueryTimeout(30);  // set timeout to 30 sec.

   // work with the database ...
   }
 }
 catch(SQLException e)
 {
   // if the error message is "out of memory", 
   // it probably means no database file is found
   System.err.println(e.getMessage());
 }
 finally
 {
   // try to disconnect
   // ...
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latest lib from http://www.xerial.org/maven/repository/artifact/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/